# android - how to remove ActionBarDivider in Holo theme

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

I have an `Activity` with a dark `ActionBar`. I need to remove its vertical dividers since my icons already have "built-in" dividers.
What I've tried goes below

Activity style:

```
     <style name="sMain" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
```

MyActionBar:

```
   <style name="MyActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@null</item>
</style>
```

This doesn't have any effect. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `android:actionBarStyle` attribute as part of the activity theme, not as part of the action bar style.

So I believe this should work:

```
<style name="sMain" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@null</item>
</style>
```

How to tell where attributes belong? I used to struggle with this too (usually solved by trial-and-error) until I discovered the use of the `android.R.styleable` class! Have a look here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html

If you do a search in the page for `actionBarStyle` you will see it shows up as `Theme_actionBarStyle`, meaning it is part of the `Theme` style (remember there is no *technical* difference between a theme and a style). If you do a search on `ActionBar_` you will be able to iterate through all of the attributes that can be set as part of an `ActionBar` style.